# DOM is rendering before Firebase is complete

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am grabbing some data from Firebase to display on my webpage. While the text is loaded correctly, I keep getting errors in my console saying that I am loading undefined variables. This is important because I eventually want to be able to add an edit feature. I determined that the Firebase call is rendering after the DOM is loaded and that the data is set to null initially.

I've tried to use different lifecycle hooks but none of them wait till the Firebase call is complete. I am not that experienced with Javascript so I may be missing something simple.

```
created(){
    db.collection('recipes').doc("Grilled Cheese").get()
        .then((doc) => {
            this.contentData = doc.data();
        })
}

data() {
    return {
        sidebarData: null,
        contentData: "",
    }
},
```

I want to populate the contentData with the correct values before the DOM renders completely.

Comment: You can render it only after you get needed data. For that purpose use directive `v-if="someData"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that you can't force the mounted hooks to be executed after the created hook ends ( the DOM render will not wait for your firebase response ) ... you need to add a conditional `v-if` on your template so only if the data is available ( not `undefined` ) the DOM will be rendered.

```
<template v-if="contentData">...</template>
```

**NB :** `null` and `""` are defined data and that should not cause any rendering issues ... make sure `doc.data()` is not `undefined`

Comment: So this fixed the errors from displaying but didn't fix the problem. I think I need to expand on the problem before asking next time